# How to Ban CNAME redirection to my Website?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cname

I'm used to buy over 15 domains per week, but sometime I may buy some domains that were used for bad things in the past and their reputation is so bad that if I don't add TLS, browsers flag it as a bad one.

On 2 of those bad domains I found that other bad domains are CNAME redirected to mine. Meaning when somebody accesses that domain it gets my content.

How can I ban that domain from CNAME redirecting visitors to mine?

I tried banning Frame viewing my Website, but it doesn't work. I still see people coming from that referrer.